# Is there a way to turn all node.js require statements into one JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to take all of the node require statements and recursively unpack them until I have a single, large, dependency-free JavaScript file. Is this possible? From what I can tell, Browserify is not what I want since it also uses require statements and external libraries. I would like no external files, just one `.js` file that can do everything on its own. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a doozy. Can you elaborate on why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you want a module bundler like webpack, rollup, parcel, etc.

Comment: @DanO could you elaborate? I tried Browserify, but it didn't do what I wanted. Is webpack any better? Just one file, no dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Just move them all to a function on a separate file. Import and execute the function in the index.js/server.js file